# RestEntity Not Working returns empty Body

Tags: java, json, spring

I am using spring 2.0.5 Release as Parent. I am  new to Spring. And I am using this API https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/2487956/ to try and display it using Object Mapper and I am having an issue with RestTemplate.

```
public void read() throws IOException {
     RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
     ResponseEntity<String> response  = rest.getForEntity("https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/2487956", String.class);
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(response.getBody());
     JsonNode name = root.path("weather_state_name");

     System.out.println(response.getBody());
}
```

Comment: You should first make sure that `response.getStatusCode()` is equal to `HttpStatus.OK`. Otherwise the request is failed hence empty body is reasonable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RestEntity is fine you're not parsing your response properly. The weather_state_name is in an array named consolidated_weather. Something following will work a/c to your needs.

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(response.getBody());
        JsonNode consolidated_weather =root.get("consolidated_weather");
        consolidated_weather.forEach(x -> {

            System.out.println( x.get("weather_state_name"));
        });
```